# How to disable Save-As Dialog dropdown menu?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, system-settings, gsettings, dialog

When I go to save stuff, a dropdown appears that I want to disable. I never use the dropdown and it gets in the way of functional use by requiring additional clicks to get rid of it.

How can I disable it so it never appears? In GNOME privacy settings I have file history disabled but this doesn't help solve the problem.

[image: Screenshot of dropdown]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Different versions mean different version of Gnome.

Comment: Good question, but afaik, you cannot disable that dropdown, which is populated by files in your current directory and filtered according to what you typed thus far (of course, you can directly select a name from the dropdown instead of continuing to type - with clicks or without clicks as you choose).

Comment: The issue occurs in all recent gnomes from 3.38 to 42. Is there any hack to disable this?